# Kotlin, How to wait for a lateinit variable to be initialized when it is being initialized in another method which is called in a different class

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin

I have a lateinit variable called currentUser in ChatActivity. This variable is initialized in onCreate by calling a method. This method calls another method in another class which handles the database. This method from database class calls onSuccess method in ChatActivity and passes the value as argument.
Since this process takes some time the later code in onCreate does not work since the variable is not initialized. what should i do to halt the onCreate methods until the variable is initialize?

this is my current code

```
private lateinit var currentUser: User
```

```
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_product_chat)

        setupActionBar()

        getUserDetails()

        if(currentUser.id == mProductDetails.user_id) {
            isSeller = true
    }
```

calling firebase method

```
    private fun getUserDetails() {
        showProgressDialog(resources.getString(R.string.please_wait))
        FireStoreClass().getUserDetails(this)
    }
```

firebase method calls this method

```
    fun userDetailsSuccess(user: User) {
        Log.e("user", "success")
        hideProgressDialog()
        hideProgressDialog()
        currentUser = user

    }
```

onSuccessListener in firebase class

```
    addOnSuccessListener { document ->
                when (activity) {
                    is ProductChatActivity -> {
                        activity.userDetailsSuccess(user)
                    }
            }
    }
```

Comment: What exact exactly would you like to do with the `currentUser` object?

Answer (score 1):

I don't quite understand your architecture, but IMO you can try to make `currentUser` observable and listen to its change.

```
val currentUser: MutableLiveData<User> by lazy {
    MutableLiveData<User>()
}


override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
   super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
   setContentView(R.layout.activity_product_chat)

   setupActionBar()

   getUserDetails()

   currentUser.observe(this, Observer { 
     if(currentUser.id == mProductDetails.user_id) {
        isSeller = true
     }
   })
}
```